# How to change validation error message using react-hook-form-mui library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, material-ui

I'm trying to learn react-hook-form-mui library. This project has quite short piece of documentation. I've tried different approaches but unfortunately none of them work. All I need is to add validation rule to my form field. Here is my functional component code.

```
export default function FormDialog({ showDialog, closeDialog }) {

    const onSumbit = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    }

    const onError = (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    }

    const { register, setError, formState: { errors } } = useForm()

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog
                open={showDialog}
                onClose={closeDialog}
                maxWidth={'xl'}
            >
                <FormContainer
                    onSuccess={onSumbit}
                    onError={onError}
                >
                    <DialogTitle>ADD Item</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText>
                            Please fill form fields
                        </DialogContentText>
                            <div>
                                <TextFieldElement
                                    {...register("NAME", { required: "Error message" })} 
                                    sx={{ width: '100px' }}
                                    className={styles.formField}
                                    name={"NAME"}
                                    label={"Name"}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button type={'submit'} variant={'contained'} color={'primary'}>
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={closeDialog}>Cancel</Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </FormContainer>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to use `{...register(name, { options })` approach from react-hook-form v7 library but this doesn't seem to be the right way to do it and I get this object from `console.log(error)`

```
{"NAME":{"type":"required","message":"This field is required","ref":{}}}
```

instead of

```
{"NAME":{"type":"required","message":"Error message","ref":{}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the RHF MUI [source code](https://github.com/dohomi/react-hook-form-mui/blob/master/packages/rhf-mui/src/TextFieldElement.tsx), the `TextFieldElement` component is already a controlled input that uses [the `Controller` component](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller/controller), which means you don't need to register it again with [the `register` method](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register).

Instead, the `TextFieldElement` has the `validation` prop that you can pass your validation rules into.

```
<TextFieldElement name="NAME" validation={{ required: "Error message" }} />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Works like a charm. I didn't manage to discover that by myself even though I knew that TextFieldElement component should provide everything needed.